# how to link an external folder to my tomcat 8 application

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, tomcat

I need to link an external folder located in : Tomcat_8/folder to an application I have located in : Tomcat_8/wtpwebapps/APP

I tried adding a context in server.xml :

```
<Context docBase="/Users/Mac/Documents/apache-tomcat-8.0.32/folder" path="/APP/images"/>
```

It works but tomcat keeps deleting this line and I read that its not a good idea to place contexts inside `server.xml`.

I added the same line in  :

- context.xml
- conf/catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml
- conf/catalina/localhost/myapp@images.xml
- conf/catalina/localhost/myapp.xml
- APP_FOLDER/WEB_INF/context.xml

Nothing works at all except the `server.xml` one.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what exactly you want to do with the folder actually. One way is do write a script that is called **setenv.sh/setenv.bat** and place it in the bin directory of Tomcat. The content of that script would be for example definition of environment variables for the path/file(s) you want to be available to the application. You do not need to change anything else - Tomcat startup script by default will invoke the file called **setenv.sh/setenv.bat** in the bin directory if it exists there. Let's say you define the directory **MYPATH =/APP/images** in your **setenv.sh** and then you can access the directory from your app using the **MYPATH** variable that is avaialble to the Tomcat instance while running.